# Node.js mysql error handling in promise

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm using node.js and express, also mysql. 
I use a connection pool to request connections and create a promise on it, to limit callback nightmare, the following snippet is set in a file that I import later, note that that I set an handler on `error` to not terminate the application in case of anything going really wrong

```
exports.getConnection = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(`Could not obtain the connection from the pool: ${err}`);
            }
            connection.on('error', err => {
                console.log(`SQL error (code: ${err.code}, message: ${err.sqlMessage}) while executing query: ${err.sql}`);
            });
            resolve(connection);
        });
    });
};
```

And here is an example of usecase (the idea is to get the connection, chain the query in the `then`, and if a non fatal error happen I will throw it and handle the connection release in the `catch` handler

```
// Exception handler that release the connection then call the callback
function releaseConnectionHandler(err, connection, callback) {
    connection.release();
    callback(err, null);
}
exports.someRequest = function(ID, callback) {
    sqlPool.getConnection().then(connection => {
        connection.query("SELECT * from tableNotExists",
                        (err, result) => {
            if (err) { 
                throw ({ err, connection, callback }); 
            }
            connection.release();
            callback(null, result);
            });
    }).catch(({ err, connection, callback}) => releaseConnectionHandler(err, connection, callback));
};
```

The query will fail, but I see that the handler is not even called (I put some trace in it...) and the application terminates on

```
node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
```

Correct querie yoeld no troubles...Any ideas what I did wrong on the error handling ?

Comment: Instead of throwing the error, you should reject the promise. Also, your code above mixes single and double quotes on your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're re-throwing the error passed to the callback of your query, which the library you're using then re-throws as well, and finally isn't properly caught and handled anywhere and results in a failure. You're not in the context of the Promise when you `throw`, but the context of the callback function called from the `mysql` module.

You're also unnecessarily mixing promises and callbacks, in particular the function you're exporting. Your question indicates that you want to move away from callbacks, so I'm going to base this answer on that indication.

To solve the main issue, don't throw the error. Instead, pass it up to the callee:

```
const promisify = require("util").promisify;

exports.someRequest = function (ID) {
  return sqlPool.getConnection().then(connection => {
    return promisify(connection.query)("select * from tableNotExist")
      .finally(connection.release);
  });
};
```

The connection will always be released back to the pool, whether successful or on error. You can then call the method with:

```
yourModule.someRequest(id).then((results) => {
  // Do something with the result set
}).catch((e) => {
  // Handle error. Can be either a pool connection error or a query error.
});
```

If you have the possibility to use `async/await`, the code can be rewritten:

```
const promisify = require("util").promisify;

exports.someRequest = async function (ID) {
  let connection = await sqlPool.getConnection();
  try {
    return await promisify(connection.query)("select * from tableNotExist");
  } finally {
    connection.release();
  }
};
```

I also recommend using [`node-mysql2`](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) since they have a Promise-based API in addition to their callback-style API and in my experience better performance as well. Then you don't have to write these tedious wrappers and instead just `require('mysql2/promise')` and be good to go.

Comment: As an additional question, why would the return promise still remember the enclosing `try{...} finally {...}` block  ? Coming from C++ this seems very weird,  I would not think this has anything to do with closure, since AFAIK this deals with enclosing variables not try-catch-finally specifiers ?

Comment: @zebullon Apologies, I missed adding an `await` before returning it. The previous solution did have a bug that would release the connection back to the pool before the query was complete. With the `await` expression there now, it will first wait for the query to complete before executing the `finally`-block (and returning the value). Does that make sense?

Comment: I should also explain the reasoning behind adding `try/finally`-clauses to this function. If the `connection.query()` throw an error, execution stops there and the error propagates up to the callee, meaning the `connection.release()` would never be executed. Wrapping the two calls in a `try` and `finally`-clause ensures that the `connection.release()`-method gets called even on an error. However, if `sqlPool.getConnection()` errors, we don't have a connection to release back to the pool, hence why it's put *outside* the `try`-clause.

Comment: If you're unsure about the execution flow, I've setup a repl for you [here](https://repl.it/repls/AquamarineStunningCache). Study and run the three functions  `getData`, `getDataConnectionError` and `getDataQueryError` to better understand.